# can't load 2 products using load by id method in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Friends, I wanna load 2 bundle products using load by id method. this is the code that i have written for that...

```
<?php
   $bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
   $stdid=$bundled->getIdBySku('123457');
   $compid=$bundled->getIdBySku('123458');

   /*get additional options of the each products*/
    $y=$bundled->load($compid);
    $selectionCollection_complete = $y->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                $y->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($y), $y);

    $x=$bundled->load($stdid);
    $selectionCollection_standard = $x->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                $x->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($x), $x);


     /*store the option head name to an array for future 
      reference*/            
     foreach($selectionCollection_standard as $std_opt)
     {
        $opt_std_hd_names.=$std_opt->getName()."<BR>";
     }
     foreach($selectionCollection_complete as $cmp_opt)
     {
       $opt_cmp_hd_names.=$cmp_opt->getName()."<BR>";
     }


     $display="<pre>".print_r($opt_std_hd_names."<br><br>".$opt_cmp_hd_names)."</pre>"
?>
```

but my problem is **$opt_std_hd**_names and **$opt_cmp_hd_names** returns the same output and they are those options of product which i have loaded first.(in this case $y. if i place the $x code at first, then it displays options of $x).the output is shown below.

```
  output:

   Preparation and Filing of Incorporation Documents
   Verify Business Name Availability
   Unlimited Phone/Email Support
   24/7 Access to Our Online Status Center
   FREE Registered Agent Service for 6 Months
   BizComply (free with your Registered Agent Service)
   500 Four-Color Business Cards
   Business License Application Package
   Palo Alto's Business Plan Pro


   Preparation and Filing of Incorporation Documents
   Verify Business Name Availability
   Unlimited Phone/Email Support
   24/7 Access to Our Online Status Center
   FREE Registered Agent Service for 6 Months
   BizComply (free with your Registered Agent Service)
   500 Four-Color Business Cards
   Business License Application Package
   Palo Alto's Business Plan Pro
```

you can see the outputs are same. why it happens like this?? please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
$bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

that's referencing the same model object and you're using it for both loading operations.
Every time you run the getIdBySku() method, the model's data is overwritten and every variable referencing this model will be updated, too.

Try to instantiate a new object or retrieve data in this way:

```
$stdid  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('123457');
$compid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('123458');
```

Comment: yes that is correct. I already figured out it and applied in my application. But I really didnt understand what was the problem for my first method. Now the things become much clear when you explained it. thank you so much for your proper guidance...